What are some of the potential legal consequences for an insurance adjuster who engages in bribery?
Please consider the following three people and the following sequence of events...

The People Involved

Omay Nernew (Home Owner)
Justin the Claim Adjuster
Aggie the Insurance Company Representative.


The Sequence of Events


Mr. Omay Nernew (the Home Owner) purchases a house in year X.


Mr. Omay Nernew (the Home Owner) purchases an insurance policy on the house from Aggie the Insurance Company Representative in year X.


Mr. Omay Nernew pays his insurance premiums for two years.


Two years later, in year (X + 2), Mr. Omay Nernew discovers that the roof is leaking after a hail storm.


Mr. Omay Nernew (the Home Owner) files a claim with Aggie the Insurance Company Representative in year (X + 2).

Aggie the Insurance Company Representative denies the claim.

Mr. Omay Nernew (the Home Owner) hires Justin the claims adjuster.

Justin, the claims adjuster, pays bribe money to   Aggie the Insurance Company Representative.

Aggie the Insurance Company Representative re-opens the claim, and the insurance company pays Mr. Omay Nernew (the Home Owner) a very large amount of money.

Mr. Omay Nernew (the Home Owner) gives some of the money to a handyman to fix the roof. All leftover money goes to Justin, the claims adjuster, and to Aggie the Insurance Company Representative, and to  Mr. Omay Nernew (the Home Owner).




What is Justin's liability in this case? Is prison time a possibility in the United States, in the state of Colorado?

In the United States, in the state of Colorado, how many years might the insurance claim adjuster (Justin the Adjuster) spend in prison for bribing Aggie the Insurance Company Representative?

Wouldn't this scenario also be a form of imbezzlement by Aggie since she's getting paid with insurance money she authorised?

Up to 3 years in prison
switzerland
The law on bribery in the private sector is rather new, these articles are effective from 1/7/2016:

StGB Art 322octies Abs 1: Any person who offers, promises or gives an employee, partner, agent or any other auxiliary of a third party in the private sector an undue advantage for that person or a third party in order that the person carries out or fails to carry out an act in connection with his official activities which is contrary to his duties or dependent on his discretion shall be liable to a custodial sentence not exceeding three years or to a monetary penalty.


Art 322novies Abs 1:  Any person who as an employee, partner, agent or any other auxiliary of a third party in the private sector demands, secures the promise of, or accepts an undue advantage for himself or for a third party in order that the person carries out or fails to carry out an act in connection with his official activities which is contrary to his duties or dependent on his discretion shall be liable to a custodial sentence not exceeding three years or to a monetary penalty.

Since in the original poster's story, everybody knew of the bribery, they may all face justice.

For purposes of clarification, I will note that "OP" is "original poster". The last sentence of your response is equivalent to, "in the original poster's story, everybody know of the bribery, they may all face justice." I have never been good at wrote memorizing abbreviations, initialisms, or acronyms. For example, NSW is an initialism of New South Wales and mkdir is an abbreviation of make directory.

12-18 months imprisonment
colorado
Justin is in violation of Subsection 3 of CRS Section 18-5-401, "Commercial bribery and breach of duty to act disinterestedly":

(1) A person commits a class 6 felony if he solicits, accepts, or
agrees to accept any benefit as consideration for knowingly violating
or agreeing to violate a duty of fidelity to which he is subject as:
(a) Agent or employee; [...]
(3) A person commits a class 6
felony if he confers or offers or agrees to confer any benefit the
acceptance of which would be a felony under subsections (1) and (2) of
this section.

Aggie is in violation of Subsection 1.  If Omay was complicit in the bribery, he might be in violation of Subsection 3 as well.
Under CRS Section 18-1.3-401, a class 6 felony is punishable by 12-18 months imprisonment (V.5) and/or a fine of $1,000 to $100,000 (III).

It seems to me that without any specific law the whole sequence would have just been an ordinary fraud with all the consequences. What is the reason to have specific laws against “fraud because of bribery”?

Up to 7 years imprisonment
new-south-wales
Section 249B of the Crimes Act 1900 makes it a crime to corruptly give or receive any benefit for an agent to do or not do stuff.

I should have tagged my question united states. Ideally, people could filter questions on law.stackexchange so that they view only questions and answers for Australia or view only questions and answers for the United States. Your answer is correct for law in New South Wales, which is a state on the east coast of Australia. I was mostly interested in law for the state of Colorado in the United States of America, but some readers like to read content for Australia.

@SamuelMuldoon You might not be aware of this decision. Answers are encouraged also if they address a different country than for which the question was asked. There might just be no one around that can answer the question for Colorado specifically.
